# How to create a dictionary with the following DataFrame

Tags: python, dictionary

Considering a dataframe with the following shape:

```
label      method      args
Cluster 0  relayout    ['shapes', 1]
Cluster 1  relayout    ['shapes', 3]
Cluster 2  relayout    ['shapes', 4]
```

I want to to create a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'buttons': [
  {'label': 'Cluster 0', 'method': 'relayout', 'args': ['shapes', 1]},
  {'label': 'Cluster 1', 'method': 'relayout', 'args': ['shapes', 3]},
  {'label': 'Cluster 2', 'method': 'relayout', 'args': ['shapes', 4]},
  ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [df.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

```
res = {'buttons': df.to_dict(orient='records')}
```